# concatenation nonblank value vba

Tags: vba, concatenation

I need to concatenate rows in 2 columns only for unique id.
Jeeped helped me with below code

```
Option Explicit
Sub qwewreq()
    Dim rw As Long
    With Worksheets("Sheet3")
        For rw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1 To 2 Step -1
            If .Cells(rw, "A").Value2 = .Cells(rw + 1, "A").Value2 Then
                .Cells(rw, "B") = .Cells(rw, "B").Value2 &Chr(10) & .Cells(rw + 1, "B").Value2
                .Cells(rw, "C") = .Cells(rw, "C").Value2 &Chr(10) & .Cells(rw + 1, "C").Value2
                .Rows(rw + 1).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next rw
    End With
End Sub
```

I try to add a symbol after every nonblank value. Above code adds symbol after every cell. Is it possible somehow to modify this code so Chr(10) could be added only after nonblank?

Thanks! That helped!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if column B is blank, then do not include line feed.
You can do this a couple ways.
One way is an inline iif.

```
Option Explicit
Sub qwewreq()
    Dim rw As Long
    With Worksheets("Sheet3")
        For rw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1 To 2 Step -1
            If .Cells(rw, "A").Value2 = .Cells(rw + 1, "A").Value2 Then
                .Cells(rw, "B") = .Cells(rw, "B").Value2 & iif(len(.Cells(rw, "B").Value2)>0,Chr(10),"") & .Cells(rw + 1, "B").Value2
                .Cells(rw, "C") = .Cells(rw, "C").Value2 & iif(len(.Cells(rw, "C").Value2)>0,Chr(10),"") & .Cells(rw + 1, "C").Value2
                .Rows(rw + 1).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next rw
    End With
End Sub
```

Another way, a little lengthier but easier to read:

```
Option Explicit
Sub qwewreq()
    Dim rw As Long
    With Worksheets("Sheet3")
        For rw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1 To 2 Step -1
            If .Cells(rw, "A").Value2 = .Cells(rw + 1, "A").Value2 Then
                if len(.Cells(rw, "B").Value2) > 0 then
                    .Cells(rw, "B") = .Cells(rw, "B").Value2 &Chr(10) & .Cells(rw + 1, "B").Value2
                else
                    .Cells(rw, "B") = .Cells(rw + 1, "B").Value2
                end if
                if len(.Cells(rw, "C").Value2) > 0 then
                    .Cells(rw, "C") = .Cells(rw, "C").Value2 &Chr(10) & .Cells(rw + 1, "C").Value2
                else    
                    .Cells(rw, "C") = .Cells(rw + 1, "C").Value2
                end if
                .Rows(rw + 1).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next rw
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear.  Hopefully, I understood it enough to answer:

```
Option Explicit
Sub qwewreq()
Dim rw As Long
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For rw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1 To 2 Step -1
        If .Cells(rw, "A").Value2 = .Cells(rw + 1, "A").Value2 Then
            If .Cells(rw + 1, "B").Value2 <> "" Then
            .Cells(rw, "B") = .Cells(rw, "B").Value2 & Chr(10) & .Cells(rw + 1, "B").Value2
            Else
            .Cells(rw, "B") = .Cells(rw, "B").Value2
            End If
            If .Cells(rw + 1, "C").Value2 <> "" Then
            .Cells(rw, "C") = .Cells(rw, "C").Value2 & Chr(10) & .Cells(rw + 1, "C").Value2
            Else
            .Cells(rw, "C") = .Cells(rw, "C").Value2 & Chr(10)
            End If
            .Rows(rw + 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next rw
End With
End Sub
```